# GROUP_CONCAT without limit by WHERE

Tags: mysql, group-concatenation

`Buildings` and `Facilities` have a many-to-many relation with a linking table of ids in between.  I would like to select Buildings with specific Facilities, and also show each Building's *other* Facilities in a single column.

Using GROUP_CONCAT works if I SELECT based on TABLE `Buildings`,

```
SELECT `b`.`building_name`, `b`.`address`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(`ft`.`facility_type` ORDER BY `facility_type`) AS `facilities`
FROM `buildings` `b`
JOIN `buildings_2_facilities` USING (`building_id`)
JOIN `facility_types` `ft` USING (`facility_id`)
WHERE `b`.`latitude` > 1
GROUP BY `building_id`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceec20/10

but if I also SELECT based on Facilities, *only* that Facility is returned in the GROUP_CONCAT.

```
SELECT `b`.`building_name`, `b`.`address`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(`ft`.`facility_type` ORDER BY `facility_type`) AS `facilities`
FROM `buildings` `b`
JOIN `buildings_2_facilities` USING (`building_id`)
JOIN `facility_types` `ft` USING (`facility_id`)
WHERE `b`.`latitude` > 1 AND `facility_id` = 2
GROUP BY `building_id`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceec20/11

How can I return results including all of each Building's facilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `b`.`building_name`, `b`.`address`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(`ft`.`facility_type` ORDER BY `facility_type`) AS `facilities`,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE `facility_id` WHEN 2 THEN `ft`.`facility_type` END ORDER BY `facility_type`) AS `facilities2`
FROM `buildings` `b`
JOIN `buildings_2_facilities` USING (`building_id`)
JOIN `facility_types` `ft` USING (`facility_id`)
WHERE `b`.`latitude` > 1
GROUP BY `building_id`;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceec20/13

> do you know a way to get rid of the rows with NULL for facilities2 in the third query?

We cannot refer to alias from output list in WHERE clause. To remove records with `facilities2 IS NULL` we must use appropriate condition in HAVING clause:

```
SELECT `b`.`building_name`, `b`.`address`, 
GROUP_CONCAT(`ft`.`facility_type` ORDER BY `facility_type`) AS `facilities`,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE `facility_id` WHEN 2 THEN `ft`.`facility_type` END) AS `facility2`
FROM `buildings` `b`
JOIN `buildings_2_facilities` USING (`building_id`)
JOIN `facility_types` `ft` USING (`facility_id`)
WHERE `b`.`latitude` > 1 
GROUP BY `building_id`
HAVING `facility2` IS NOT NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceec20/17

Comment: Thank you, but do you know a way to get rid of the rows with NULL for facilities2 in the third query?  I tried http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceec20/15